# Valgrind memory leak with linked lists

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

When I run my program with valgrind I notice I only have a small memory leak (2 blocks) when I implement this function. This removes the node and when the list is printed out the node no longer appears.

```
car *removeCar(car *head, char *targetModel) {

car *temp=head;
car *temp2=head->next;

if(strcmp(temp->model,targetModel)==0) {
    return head;
}

while(temp2!=NULL) {
    if(strcmp(temp2->model,targetModel)==0) {

        temp->next=temp2->next;
        free(temp2);

        return head;
    }

    temp=temp->next;
    temp2=temp2->next;
}

return head;
}
```

Here is my free function. It has been freeing the memory just fine until I choose to call the removeCar function.

```
void freeMem(car *head) {/*Function frees all memory allocated to linked lists*/

car *current=NULL;

while((current=head)!=NULL) {
    head=head->next;
    free(current->model);
    free(current->color);
    free(current);
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb. I suspect that you *intended* to call `freeMem(temp2)`, but by force of habit you called `free(temp2)`, so that you leak the `model` and `color`.

Comment: Call `free(temp2->model);` and `free(temp2->color);` before you call `free(temp2);` Calling `freeMem(temp2)` will free the entire list from temp2 onwards instead of a single item.

Comment: `if(strcmp(temp->model,targetModel)==0) {
    return head;
}` appears wrong.  I'd expect it would free memory, some memory, like the `if(strcmp(temp2->model,targetModel)==0) {` block does.

Comment: it would be easier to review your code and answer this if you formatted your code with proper indentation and you also included the code that allocates the memory and that calls the freeMem() function.

Answer (score 0):

With linked lists I used to add an extra indirection, so I don't need the extra handling when dealing with the head of the list.

```
car *removeCar(car *head, char *targetModel) 
{
    car * * ppNode = &head;
    while (*ppNode)
    {
        car* pCurrent = *ppNode;
        if(strcmp(pCurrent->model,targetModel)==0) 
        {
           //replace the reference to pCurrent by its successor
           *ppNode = pCurrent->next;
           free(pCurrent->model);
           free(pCurrent->color);
           free(pCurrent);
           break;
        }
        ppNode = &pCurrent->next;
    }
    return head; //possibly changed
}
```